# Could not locate module ... mapped as for one of my packges

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I have a `my-dependency-package` which is an NPM package that I'm using, which includes `lib/utils/list-utils`.

I have `my-package` which uses `my-dependency-package` as a dependency. When I try to build it, I get this error:

```
FAIL  test/some-file.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run
    Configuration error:
    Could not locate module lib/utils/list-utils mapped as:
    /some-path/my-package/lib/utils/list-utils.
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^lib\/(.*)$/": "/some-path/my-package/lib/$1"
      },
      "resolver": null
    }
      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:501:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@amzn/quicksilver-commons-cdk/lib/pipelines/quicksilver-pipeline.ts:4:1)
 FAIL  test/stack/order-aggregation-goldbox-lambda-stack.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run
    Configuration error:
    Could not locate module lib/utils/list-utils mapped as:
    /some-path/my-package/lib/utils/list-utils.
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^lib\/(.*)$/": "/some-path/my-package/lib/$1"
      },
      "resolver": null
    }
```

This is the `package.json` for `my-package`:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf ./build && rm -rf ./dist && rm -rf node_modules",
    "test": "npm run lint && jest --passWithNoTests",
    "posttest": "generate-coverage-data",
    "prettier": "prettier bin/**/*.ts lib/*.ts lib/**/*.ts --write",
    "lint": "eslint '**/*.{ts,js}'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // some dependencies
    "my-dependency-package": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // some devDependencies
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "lib": "lib"
  }
}
```

And finally `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2016", "es2017.object", "es2017.string"],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
        "lib/*": ["lib/*"],
        "test/*": ["test/*"],
      }
  },
  "exclude": ["cdk.out"]
}
```

In case of need, I can share also same files for `my-dependency-package`.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the error stack trace, I would say that jest is misconfigured.

```
● Test suite failed to run
    Configuration error:
    Could not locate module lib/utils/list-utils mapped as:
    /some-path/my-package/lib/utils/list-utils.
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^lib\/(.*)$/": "/some-path/my-package/lib/$1"
      },
      "resolver": null
    }
```

You may want to create a `jest.config.ts` file and add it to the arguments of your test command using `--config` flag.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring